# How to stack images using ng-repeat in a gallery view?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a gallery. I'm trying to show image in the gallery through ng-repeat.

The images are loaded however they get loaded in a linear pattern (as I used list) but I want them to load up in grid system. Three image per row.

Is it possible to create something like this

```
<ul ng-repeat = "x in dogObj">

    <div class ="row">
        <div class ="col-lg-4">
            <li class ="list-group-item" text-align><img src="{{x.src}}" height="350" width = "400"></li>
        </div>  
    </div>

</ul>
```

The json file is embedded inside the controller

```
app.controller("myCtrl", 

    function($scope)  
    {
       $scope.dogObj =    [{"actual_name":"dog1","shown_name":"dog1","src":"images/dog1.jpg"},
                          {"actual_name":"dog2","shown_name":"dog2","src":"images/dog2.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog3","shown_name":"dog3","src":"images/dog3.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog7","shown_name":"dog7","src":"images/dog7.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog4","shown_name":"dog4","src":"images/dog4.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog5","shown_name":"dog5","src":"images/dog5.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog6","shown_name":"dog6","src":"images/dog6.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog8","shown_name":"dog8","src":"images/dog8.jpg"}];});
```

I've put up the image location in a json file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to modify your dogObj.

Comment: Hey Sudhir could you please elaborate on that!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1-** Using `li` tag as direct child of `ul` tag is a good practice.

**2-** Your iterator (`ng-repeat`) I think must be used in `li` tag, not `ul` tag.

**3-** You can instead of using `src="{{}}"` use `ng-src=""` directive.

I think this code is your answer

```
<ul class="row">
  <li class="col-lg-4" ng-repeat="x in dogObj">

    <div class="list-group-item" text-align>
      <img ng-src="x.src" height="350" width="400">
    </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Its about to show three image in one iteration. Please read question carefully and then try to answer otherwise you will get downvote.

Comment: `Three image per row.` @SudhirOjha

Comment: Yes @Saeed.Ataee

Answer (score 0):

Usually you iterate over the row, something like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat = "x in dogObj">
    <div class ="col-lg-4">
        <img src="{{x.src}}" height="350" width = "400"></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your example creates illformed html (check relation of ul and li elements).
How does you JSON look like? You will also get a problem with the sizes of the images within the responsive layout.

ng-repeat does not provide a lot of logic (which is a good thing, you don't want too much logic in your view). If you want 3 images per row you will have to arange your data in triples, like so

```
data = [ [ dogObj, dogObj, dogObj ] , ... ]
```

and then iterate over the list, and create one row of each triplett as shown before. 
Simpler but not as clean: You could also render all images in one row and rely on the responsive layout to render many rows using the correct css class

```
...
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img ...
...
```

which essentially tells the browser to render 3 columns regardless of the screen size. The row will break to the next line. Still the image sizes will break this. bootstrap provides the class .img-responsive, that could help.
Check out the documentation of the grid system and img-responsive at www.getbootstrap.com

Anyway a better option might be to show less columns if the screen size get too small and more if the screen is really big.

Comment: Hey Christoph,
I'm trying to implement three images in one row using the bootstrap module. 
The images do get printed using img however it shows up one row at a time.

Is there any way that I can get three images to show up in one iteration of the loop yet having the images remain unique

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this code this is 100% working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat = "x in dogObj">
            <div class ="col-lg-4">
                <img src="{{x.src}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.dogObj =    [{"actual_name":"dog1","shown_name":"dog1","src":"images/dog1.jpg"},
            {"actual_name":"dog2","shown_name":"dog2","src":"images/dog2.jpg"},
            {"actual_name":"dog3","shown_name":"dog3","src":"images/dog3.jpg"},
            {"actual_name":"dog7","shown_name":"dog7","src":"images/dog7.jpg"},
            {"actual_name":"dog4","shown_name":"dog4","src":"images/dog4.jpg"},
            {"actual_name":"dog5","shown_name":"dog5","src":"images/dog5.jpg"},
            {"actual_name":"dog6","shown_name":"dog6","src":"images/dog6.jpg"},
            {"actual_name":"dog8","shown_name":"dog8","src":"images/dog8.jpg"}];});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```